# Register custom annotation in Java

Tags: java, guice, javalin

I’m working on a project using only the Javalin framework and google Guice inject.

I’m having a hard time recording a custom annotation in the project to be used by any class

I created a custom annotation to make a regex in a string of a class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Regex {}
```

Here is the implementation for this annotation

```
public class RegexProcessor {

    public static void process(Object obj) {
        Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Regex.class) && field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
                try {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    String originalValue = (String) field.get(obj);
                    if (originalValue != null) {
                        String result = originalValue .replaceAll("\\s+","");
                        field.set(obj, result);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    log.error("error: ", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use my note, I have to do this

```
ExampleClass example = new ExampleClass(" Hollo Word ");
RegexProcessor.process(example); // I want to have to do it every time
System.out.println(example.getText());
```

Class

```
class ExampleClass {
        @Regex
        private String text;

        public ExampleClass(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        // Other fields and methods...
    }
```

If anyone has any example of how I can achieve this

Comment: This simply isn't possible in java.

Comment: Register a globally custom annotation in the project to be used by any class so I don’t have to call the annotation implementation every time, isn’t that possible in Java? I find this statement controversial

Comment: No. That's not possible or how any of this works. Annotations do only two things: [A] things you can read at runtime. There is no 'registering' nor any 'automated application'. The code you wrote here, that's all this covers, and [B] something that __compiler plugins__ can see. But they can't modify existing code short of cloning Project Lombok and doing what they do. What you try to do here is rather fundamentally runtime based, and thus, not possible either. in short: "This simply isn't possible in java".

Comment: This is probably something you _could_ do with an AOP framework, but I won't elaborate on how because I think it's not something you _should_ do.

Using standard approaches for data validation and normalization seem better and easier to both implement and maintain.